Timeout not resetting for each Promise
I am trying to make it so each mapbox cell will download. I want it so every loop has 60 seconds to download the street and satelite maps. This seems to timeout every 60 seconds regardless of whether it is successfully constantly looping and downloading maps.
So it will loop and download correctly but timeout after 60 seconds every time, instead of first loop, allow 60 seconds, finishes, second loop restart and allow 60 seconds, finishes....
They take less than 10 seconds to download so it should never timeout. I am also logging to see them finish.
const downloads = bufferedCellBBoxes.map(async (cell, i) => {
    let timeoutResolved = false; // Flag to track if the timeout has already been resolved

    const timeoutPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (!timeoutResolved) {
          resolve('timeout');
          timeoutResolved = true; // Set flag to true to indicate timeout has been resolved
        }
      }, 60000); // 60 seconds timeout
    });

    const satellitePromise = downloadMapTiles(
      'satellite',
      [
        [cell[2] as number, cell[3] as number],
        [cell[0] as number, cell[1] as number],
      ],
    );

    const streetPromise = downloadMapTiles(
      'street',
      [
        [cell[2] as number, cell[3] as number],
        [cell[0] as number, cell[1] as number],
      ],
    );

    return Promise.race([
      Promise.all([satellitePromise, streetPromise]),
      timeoutPromise,
    ])
      .then((result) => {
        // Check if the result is 'timeout', if so, cancel the ongoing processes
        if (result === 'timeout') {
          throw new Error('Timed out');
        }
        return result; // Return the resolved promise result
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error during tile download:', error);
        return Promise.reject(error);
      });
  });


Why is the function declared async? It never uses await. And it returns an explicit promise with Promise.race(), so you don't need the automatic promise created by async.

bufferedCellBBoxes length is 228. :S Is that my problem, and could you suggest a solution? Some sort of pagination style download?

Each time you call timeOutPromise you're creating a new timeout but never clearing it before the next one. bind the timeout function to a variable then clear and reset your timeout before the next iteration  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearTimeout

Sorry *Typescript in React Native.

Am I understanding correctly that you wish for 1 to complete before 2 begins? Each download has 60 seconds to complete before moving onto the next or timing out, yes?

I have worked out what I feel is a working solution.
bufferedCellBBoxes.reduce((accumulator: Promise<any>[], cell, i) => {
    let timeoutResolved = false; // Flag to track if the timeout has already been resolved

    const timeoutPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (!timeoutResolved) {
          resolve('timeout');
          timeoutResolved = true; // Set flag to true to indicate timeout has been resolved
        }
      }, 40000); // 40 seconds timeout
    });

    const satellitePromise = downloadMapTiles(
      percentIncreasePerPack,
      'satellite',
      70,
      [
        [cell[2] as number, cell[3] as number],
        [cell[0] as number, cell[1] as number],
      ],
      i,
      maxOnlineZoomCell,
      workPackId,
      crewId,
    );

    const streetPromise = downloadMapTiles(
      percentIncreasePerPack,
      'street',
      70,
      [
        [cell[2] as number, cell[3] as number],
        [cell[0] as number, cell[1] as number],
      ],
      i,
      maxOnlineZoomCell,
      workPackId,
      crewId,
    );

    const combinedPromise: Promise<any[]> = Promise.all([
      satellitePromise,
      streetPromise,
    ])
      .then((result) => {
        return result; // Return the resolved promise result
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error during tile download:', error);
        return Promise.reject(error);
      });

    const racePromise = Promise.race([
      combinedPromise,
      timeoutPromise,
    ]).then((result) => {
      // If the racePromise resolves successfully with 'timeout', set exitLoop to true
      if (result === 'timeout' && isCrewMode) {
        addNotification({
          type: 'error',
          message: `Map tile download error. If offline mode is required please log out to restart the download.`,
        });
        //exitLoop = true; // Set the control variable to true
      }
      return result; // Return the result
    });

    // Adding the combined promise to the accumulator
    accumulator.push(racePromise);

    // Ensuring only 5 promises are processed concurrently
    if (i % 5 === 4 || i === bufferedCellBBoxes.length - 1) {
      // Return the accumulator and reset it for the next batch
      const currentBatch = [...accumulator];
      accumulator.length = 0;
      return currentBatch;
    } else {
      useDownloadManagerStore.setState({
        crewDownloadPercent: 0,
      });
      return accumulator;
    }
  }, []);

